# how to determine which anchor in li element is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have this code below:

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/call" class="promo-call active-call"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/text" class="promo-text"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/data" class="promo-data"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/combo" class="promo-combo"></a> 
</li>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/recent" class="promo-recent"></a>
</li>
```

What I want to do is when the user click the class `promo-text` it will append an `active-text` in the class property

E.g:

```
<a class="promo-text active-text></a>
```

and will add this css style: `background:url(../images/call_icon_0.png) 0 -72px no-repeat!important;`

Of course i need remove the active in the other class.

Comment: Would you mind using Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: You should use Javascript here

Comment: @SayemAhmed yup. Just don't know how to apply it in my case.

Comment: @Gordon sorry, edited the tags

Comment: @WonderingCoder: See the answer below.

Comment: @Gordon actually since he uses `php` related functions in question it could be IMO. Also as I see we are coming to conclusion, that in the end he will need to do that server side. So PHP would be correct tag here. Again IMO.

Comment: @Eugene if its for PHP its a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=active+link+php+html ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using Javascript + Jquery + CSS, try the following.

First create a CSS Class like this -

```
.active-text
{
    background: url(../images/call_icon_0.png) 0 -72px no-repeat;
}
```

Then use the following JQuery code -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("li a").click(function()
    {
        $("li a.active-text").removeClass("active-text");
        $(this).addClass("active-text");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKkuW/) demo.

To add any specific CSS style to an element, use the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function -

```
$(this).css("color", "red");
```

This will dynamically add `color:red` CSS style to the selected element. You can add any CSS rule in this way.

Comment: The only thing is, that links in this example do not go anywhere. And in question they do. So it is completely different behavior.

Comment: could you make it more dynamic. I mean I have 5 images for its background. If I click promo there's a background specifically for it.   could you also add a css style in jquery?

Comment: @WonderingCoder: I have edited the answer demonstrating how to dynamically change the css style of an element.

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript & jquery you could use http://api.jquery.com/click/:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    // remove all classes
    $('li a').removeClass('active-text');

    // add class to the selected element
    $(this).addClass('active-text);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a separate class, you can use the pseudo class **a:active**

```
a.promo-text {
 /* some style */
}
a.promo-text:active {
 background:url(../images/call_icon_0.png) 0 -72px no-repeat!important;
}
```

if you have multiple backgrounds for each link,

```
a.promo-text:active {
 /* text_icon background */
}
a.promo-call:active {
 /* call_icon background */
}


a.promo-recent:active {
 /* recent_icon background */
}
```

and so on

Comment: hmmm, I have 5 different images for each anchor. Will this be ok?

Comment: yes 
a.promo-text:active {
 /* text_icon background */
}
a.promo-call:active {
 /* call_icon background */
}


a.promo-recent:active {
 /* recent_icon background */
}

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Set it manually since it will redirect to another page after clicking.

For example in call page, this will be the code:

```
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/call" class="promo-call active-text active-call"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/text" class="promo-text"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/data" class="promo-data"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/combo" class="promo-combo"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/recent" class="promo-recent"></a>
    </li>
```

In text page:

```
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/call" class="promo-call active-call"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/text" class="promo-text active-text"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/data" class="promo-data"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/combo" class="promo-combo"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/promos/recent" class="promo-recent"></a>
    </li>
```

Comment: can't do it like that. Cause I'm using a jquerymobile framework and its pages are loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS you won't be able to set a new class upon a click, you would need Javascript for that. (see xylar's response for an example)

If you are interested in changing the style upon hover, i.e. when the user moves his mouse over a list item, you could use the `li:hover` CSS directive.

Comment: i understand the part that i need to use a javascript/jquery, just don't know how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li a").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("class name here").parent().siblings().children("a").removeClass("to remove class name here");
  });
});
```

Should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, then you can't add inline style with `!important` option, therefore you should create separate class or id for, that case ( class would be better I supose ). Also. You may have more than one list on the page, therefore it is better to work with one specific, so you take closest to your li, but if your link will go somewhere ( not on page action ), then it will reload and there is no point in JavaScript. Better to add with `PHP` then. Or if you parse it with Javascript somehow or do Ajax call, then it is fine (probably).

```
<style type="text/css">
.active-text {
    background: url(../images/call_icon_0.png) 0 -72px no-repeat !important;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('li a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.closest('ul').find( 'li a' ).removeClass('active-text');

        $this.addClass('active-text);
    });
});
</script>
```